# How do I disable Bootchart?

Tags: 12.04, bootchart

I dont want a Bootchart to be generated on every startup. How do I disable bootchart ?

Once disabled, how do I re-enable bootchart ?

I don't mean **uninstall**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stopping

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo update-rc.d -f stop-bootchart remove
sudo update-rc.d -f bootchart remove
```

Re-starting

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo update-rc.d stop-bootchart start 99 2 3 4 5
```

---

or:

```
echo manual | sudo tee -a /etc/init/bootchart.override
```

makes it manual.

---

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
sudo update-rc.d -f bootchart remove
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/bootchart ...
```

Comment: Dont work in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: yes it does? see the edit.

Comment: Uhm.. it could work, but I just uninstall bootchart so I cant test the new receipt. It was eating my free space in HD